# Heartfire House Freeze Glitch

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

Now I've built all 3 houses in Hearthfire and I have moved into one, Lakeview Manor, with my wife and adopted kids.

But there is one problem, every time I add something to chests, wardrobes, drawers etc. the game freezes after a little while, and depending on how much I've put in I wont be able to go back into the house for a few days, maybe even a week, because it still freezes. The whole game, making me turn off my xbox.

It's fine if I don't put anything in, I can come and go as I please.

- Why does it do that?
- Is there a way to stop it doing that?
- Does anyone else have this same problem?

Or is it the task of simply putting up with it?

- Oh and I have giants, bandits and dragons attacking now and then, is
  that normal?

Not forgetting the dead dragon forever spawning at my house, half fallen through the ground, maybe that's causing a glitch?

Comment: Most common reason for lags and freezes in games such as Skyrim: a lack of RAM. As for the rest; sorry, can't help you, since I don't have any Skyrim DLC yet.

Comment: Did you install Skyrim to your HDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've said, you might be able to fix this problem by deleting your game data for both the main game and the DLC and reinstalling them. Make sure what you're deleting is not your saves or much sadness will occur.

Reinstalling has fixed several glitches with houses, characters, quests, physics, and so on. Personally, I had to reinstall because my game would freeze every time I tried to swim in water.